# How should I merge into main branch in Git with this structure?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-actions, git-flow

In my team, we have a repository that has two branches to deploy a website: `Main and Develop`

- **Main**: This one, is connected with the server and this branch only contain the minimal folders with the sections that the client wants.
- **Develop:** This contain all the folders with all the sections, we work on this branch and then we want to merge into main with all the changes that we do in this branch.

The problem is that a section has a subfolders and not all the files of this section are modified. So when we do the merge... only some part of section is merged and the website doesn't work.

An example of the structure

```
| Main branch | 
| ----------- |
    -httpdocs
       -layout
          +landing
    

| Develop branch | 
| -------- |
    -httpdocs
       -layout
          +landing
          +sections
             -photos
                -controller
                ---photos.php
                -viewer
                ---photos.php
             -videos
                -controller
                ---videos.php
                -viewer
                ---videos.php <-- we edit this file
```

After merge develop into main we get the following structure

```
| Main branch | 
| -------- |
    -httpdocs
       -layout
          +landing
          +sections
             -videos
                -viewer
                ---videos.php <-- we edit this file
```

And we wish that the final structure seems like that

```
| Main branch | 
| -------- |
    -httpdocs
       -layout
          +landing
          +sections
             -videos
                -controller
                ---videos.php (not edited)
                -viewer
                ---videos.php <-- we edit this file
```

Is this possible? How you should we do? We accomplished this using this command:  `git add httpdocs/layout/sections/videos` but there are some alternative?

Comment: Yeah we know, this git only contains php and html files

Comment: Branches don't contain *folders*. Branches *find commits*. Commits contain *files* but any one given commit can be, and often is, on *more than one branch at a time*. Trying to make a "branch-specific file" is a fundamental mistake in Git; don't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible you are running git add from inside the httpsdocs/layout/sections/video/viewer directory. Doing so will create the behavior you have described.

To clarify, using git add in this directory will only add the files you've changed in that directory to git tracking. I'd recommend ensuring your path is a parent of all the files you'd like to add.

Comment: But can we do automaticatly? using VSCode interface? I mean we have like 15 sections so, do this 15 times... is not worth

Comment: Do git add . from the top level directory. Due to how git works you'll only need to run it once.

Also if you are in vscode, I think opening a terminal will default you to the top level directory of your git repo

Comment: But with this all the files are gonna merge into main right? Imagine that we only edit 7 of 15 sections. Can we create some script or something that detect only the sections wich have some modify file?

Comment: git will do this already. 

You have edited some files and you want to add those to tracking. git add . will add all changes to tracking. From there git commit -m "some message" and git push will update the local branch with local changes. 

Merging will then require you to switch to your main and then merge the development branch from there. Its important that your branch is updated with all the local changes before merging

Comment: @JuanjoMB98 are you on develop or main for you git branch?